# Remove Sound Output Device

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My computer has two outputs: Internal (which I want) and Belkin S52, which I want to remove. I have tried looking this up, but most of them are for sound flower or boom. I have tried looking through extensions and audio plug-ins, but I can't find it. It, for some reason always changes my sound from internal to Belkin S52, meaning I can never hear anything unless I manually change the volume setting, and some times it just goes back to Belkin for seemingly no reason.

How do I remove this output device on a MacBook air?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the Belkin S52, but assuming it's a sound device the first thing I would try is using the Audio MIDI Setup app to remove it.

Follow these steps:

- Launch the Audio MIDI Setup (by default, this app is located in Applications > Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup)
- Once open you'll see a list of devices on the left-hand side
- Select the Belkin S52
- Now click on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button to remove it
- Follow any prompts you may get

If the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button isn't available, or the Belkin S52 isn't listed, you may need to clarify your question to include details on what the Belkin S52 is and how you installed it originally.

Comment: One more path to find an extension to remove is "/Library/Extensions"

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with Splashtop Remote virtual sound device remaining in my macOS Sound output and input device lists after uninstalling Splashtop. I was excited to find [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)'s answer. Unfortunately, the minus sign in Audio MIDI Setup was greyed out for this Splashtop driver.

The solution in my case (thanks to an [8-year old answer on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2d57t2/comment/cjm79ke/)) was finding the Splashtop driver in /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins, moving it to trash and restarting macOS. The above linked solution on reddit provides three possible locations to check for the unwanted device:

- /System/Library/Extensions
- /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins
- ~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins  (which is the above folder in your Home directory)